# How to erase multiple parameters on a URL with .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo, friendly-url

I'm trying to make my own CMS and at this moment I'm looking to get clean my URLs, but I can't erase the first GET parameter and leave just the second.
The unique thing that I did was to remove the extension file name with another `.htaccess` condition, but I can't solve this problem.

An example:

```
www.mysite.com/posts?id=2&title=The%20PostTitle
```

To:

```
www.mysite.com/posts/The%20PostTitle
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Building your own CMS is quite a lot of work. If it is really necessary you should use a framework like Symfony (PHP) as foundation.
To your question: Everything you need to know about redirects on apache can be found here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I don't really understand why you need this transformation of the URL. Usually you use the information that is stored in your database to create "talking" URLs like `http://example.net/posts/the-post-title` and then you redirect all this URLs to an index.php which then will try to make an reverse lookup to get the `ID` coresponding to the given `title`

Comment: I didn't know that. I believed that and "posts" page bring  the client just the template and later to get the url variables, i would use "$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']". Or i'm completely lost?

Comment: If you use the RewriteEngine to get rid of parameters like the ID this information is lost to PHP because for your PHP Script it looks like only the last URL was called to open this file.

Comment: So, can be necessary let it on the URL, like: www.example.com/post/1/the-posts-title right?

Comment: That would be a quite common solution.

Comment: Nice, i'll try to set it to that way. Thanks my friend!

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have an URL like `http://example.com/the/path/to/my/file.php?id=1&title=my-title`, the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`only contains the path and the file name `the/path/to/my/file.php`.

So usually you use your .htaccess to redirect everything that is not a real file to your index.php und than use `explode('/', $_SERER['REQUEST_URI']);` to resolve your path fragments, which then represent the parameters.

Comment: Nice idea! Thank you for the little class you gave me. I'm really grateful... I'll keep trying with the whole information that you shared to me. @Inceddy If i could get the solution by my own, i'll write it here to share it with the people.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^posts/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ "posts?title=$1&id=$2" [NC]
```

Comment: Nice! Now i have another question about... On that rule, where i'm going to erase the "id" parameter?

Comment: I tried with that rule, but doesn't work for me. I think, maybe i'm losing something. Thanks my friend. I'll try to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Its not tested.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /posts?id=(\d+)&title=(.*)(&*.=.*){0,1}$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/posts/[%2]/?id=%1&%3
```

Comment: I think that my server isn't completely set because i got an error 500.

Comment: Give me a sec. I'll setup an testing enviroment.

Comment: I'm really grateful, you don't how much! And i know, is just that i'm trying to practice my PDO skills with this page, but i'm lost. @Inceddy

Answer (score 0):

I found a video tutorial that can be useful to everyone who is trying to understand how to use .htaccess files.
I hope it will be very helpful on your own projects. 
 [Semantic URL htaccess Tutorial SEO Friendly Clean Links](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1pbAV6AU99I)

Thank you to everyone who tried to help me!

To the spanish speakers, you can read something about regular expresions (regex). This is the link: [Reemplazar cadenas y caracteres de un string.](http://www.intergraphicdesigns.com/blog/rapido-y-completo-expresiones-regulares-en-php/)